# Unravel the [cocoon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[cocoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoon) is supposed to be about Apache cocoon (as stated in the tag wiki), but it is sometimes used to refer to a Ruby gem (which should be [cocoon-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoon-gem)), as can be seen by there being 10 questions with it occurring with [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).

To avoid confusion, there should be a tag called [apache-cocoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-cocoon), so that any questions that use [cocoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoon) are obviously mistagged.

Comment: If the cocoon questions that really belong to cocoon-gem can be retagged by the community, I'll rename the remaining ones to apache-cocoon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the cocoon-gem questions have been retagged.